# How to Import XML into Google Sheets from web page

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import data from a website into my Google Sheets form using via IMPORTXML. The target page is `https://poporing.life/?search=:steel`, 
however both functions keep getting the data from the highlight on picture:

[image: "Steel" example]

So for example, when I try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://poporing.life/?search=:steel","//div[@class='d-flex flex-column']//div[@class='info']//b")
```

it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how do I get the data from the subpage?

Comment: Have you read the [poporing API](https://poporing.life/api-docs/)?

Answer (score 0):

The OP is attempting to use IMPORTXML to extract data from https://poporing.life. However, the site has a public API that can be used to get the same data more easily.

The [API is documented](https://poporing.life/api-docs). The output is JSON which can be easily accessed with Google sheets. Google has documented the process for accessing [External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

Using the Google and Poporing documentation, I built this code.

```
function so54549431() {

  var url = 'https://api.poporing.life/' +
    'get_latest_price/steel';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Origin": "https://poporing.life",
    }
  });
    Logger.log("DEBUG: JSON Response: " + response); //DEBUG

  // returns an Object
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //


  var itemname = dataAll.data.item_name;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Item name: " + itemname);//DEBUG

    var price = dataAll.data.data.price;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Price: " + price); //DEBUG

  var volume = dataAll.data.data.volume;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Volume: " + volume);

}
```

The JSON returned by the API for `get_lastest_price` is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "item_name": "steel",
        "data": {
            "price": 2358,
            "volume": 1190273,
            "timestamp": 1549458553,
            "snapping": -1,
            "change1day": 1.550387596899225,
            "change3day": 11.016949152542374,
            "change7day": 31.364902506963787
        }
    }
}
```